# Magento validation class

Tags: magento

I need to validate username. The user name should allow only characters and spaces. It should not accept numbers. The current validation class which allows numbers. But if I use class "validate-alpha" which is not allowing spaces. Can any one tell me which validation class should I use?

Comment: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/magento-validation-class/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create you own custom validation class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
Validation.add('validate-alpha-spac','You failed to enter baz!',function(v)        {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
});  
</script>
```

See http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation

or

```
  Validation.addAllThese([
      'validate-alpha-space', 
      'Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.', 
      function (v) { return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
 }]),
```

see http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/custom-javascript-form-validators

Comment: If you need to exclude numbers in the name you need to replace the function with this: **return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(v)** i.e avoid accepting numbers 0-9 in the name.